# Convert data attributes to unordered list

Tags: jquery, json

i have this :

```
<a href="#" data-teste='["apresentacoes/1.jpg", "apresentacoes/2.jpg", "apresentacoes/3.jpg"]'>
    <img src="apresentacoes/thumbs/1.jpg" alt="img01"/>
</a>
```

how could i trasnform the `data-teste` attribute into this:

```
<ul>
   <li><img src="apresentacoes/1.jpg"></li>
   <li><img src="apresentacoes/2.jpg"></li>
   <li><img src="apresentacoes/3.jpg"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: In what context?  When would you want to do this transformation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this demo:

```
function createList(data) {
    var parts = ['<ul>'], i = 0;

    for (; i < data.length; i++) {
         parts.push('<li><img src="' + data[i] + '"></li>');
    }
    parts.push('</ul>');

    return parts.join('');
}
```

Where `var data = $(this).data('teste');`

http://jsfiddle.net/nnfwh/

Creating a string instead of appending DOM elements in a loop is going to be a little more effective.

Comment: As i said to @adeneo, i need it working with multiple anchors, and i use yours on what i need.. and BANG!! Works sweet!!! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
var ul = $('<ul />');

$.each($('a').data('teste'), function() {
    var li  = $('<li />'),
        img = $('<img />', {src: this});

    ul.append( li.append(img) );
});

$('body').append(ul);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/z5Nmb/1/)

Comment: I think jQuery might auto-parse the JSON in the data attribute for you.  Not 100% sure though,

Comment: @RocketHazmat - just changed it, it does indeed create an array automagically.

Comment: +1 - this is a great example where `data()` is doing exactly what you want.  However, sometimes `data()` can backfire.  In cases where you actually want the exact string (for example when you have `data-id="01"`), you need to use `attr()` instead.

Comment: @adeneo if i have another anchor with the same data attribute, but with diferente values? see: http://jsfiddle.net/z5Nmb/3/ here, is always get only the attribute values from first `a`...

Comment: @Preston - indeed you would, you have to create a scope for each list -> http://jsfiddle.net/z5Nmb/4/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var div = "<ul>";
var a = $("a").attr("data-teste");
a = JSON.parse(a);
var len = a.length;
for(var i=0;i<len;i++){
    div += "<li><img src='"+a[i]+"'/></li>";
}
if(div != ""){
    div += "</ul>";
}
$("body").append(div);
```

[Fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/q8f3W/1/)